# Using flash-based UI components in Flash Builder 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flex4.5

I am trialling Flash Builder 4 Premium.

I'd like to know if it is possible to use components designed for Flash (e.g. http://www.oxylusflash.com/membership and http://www.jumpeyecomponents.com/Flash-Components/Various/JC-Collectio n-385/ , amongst many others) in Flash Builder 4? How can I import them? By import, I also mean they are first class citizens like the out-of-the-box Flash Builder 4 components.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless they implement the UIComponent class, they will not conform to the layout and other functionality traits of other "Spark" or MX components.

That means you can't use them in states, have them be part of a layout (properly), or assign them styles and skin them easily the same way that you do with a stock component.

That being said, yes... you can use them. You just need to work with outside the context of the "Flex" framework.

Comment: That is VERY disappointing. Adobe have missed the boat here. With that being the case, who are the top suppliers of Flex components?

Comment: Flextras, IBM iLog Elixr, and tons of free components. You can get "Tour de Flex" from Adobe which explores hundreds of components. I don't think you can blame this one on Adobe as their framework is open and free for anyone to incorporate. There's really no way for them to force 3rd party companies to make their components compatible and if they did, a lot of people wanting more "light weight" components would be upset that their components are bloated with Flex Framework specific stuff.